# How to invoke a function on only the first click?

Tags: javascript

I am very new to coding. I have been using javascript for about 2 weeks and downloaded VS code about a month ago. Simply to familiarize myself with JS, I am trying to make a clicks per minute test. The aspect I am struggling with is the timer. As of right now, an onclick function triggers this code (the onclick function is on the button that you click to play the test, which is an issue  because the button gets clicked more than once). I am asking for assistance in the following ways:

1. I am aware that my code is most likely not the most efficient way to do this, and I am willing to do this, and I am interested in learning how more experienced coders would go about this.
2. The function is invoked every time the button is clicked, which is a major issue. I want the timer to start on just the first click of the button during that game.
3. I want to make things happen when the timer hits 0, and I would appreciate advice about how to go about doing that.
4. I need to figure out how to reset the timer back to 20 when the user clicks the reset button.

This is the code I've written *the onclick function it paired to timer()*

```
var time=20;
function TimeDisplay(){
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=
    time;
}
function timer(){
    setInterval(TimerFunction,1000);
}
function TimerFunction(){
    if (time>0){
        time--;
        TimeDisplay();
    }
}
```

Any help you can provide to me is greatly appreciated and any constructive criticism will be graciously accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Use a boolean value, named something like `timerStarted` which is set to false initially, and in the method that starts the timer do a check, then if you are starting the timer set it to true.

```
onClick() {
  if(!timerStarted) {
     // start your interval
     timerStarted = true;
  }
}
```